# R - Apply function on every row, with data from the row

Tags: r

Is there a faster way to do this:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(dataframe))
{
dataframe$results <- with(dataframe, myownfunction(column1[i],
  column2[i], column3[i], column4[i], column5[i], column6[i])
}
```

`myownfunction` finds implied volatility using `uniroot()`, but when `uniroot` does not find a solution it stops (usually because there some faults in the data), and the loop stops. Is there a way to make the function just output `NA` if it gets an error from `uniroot` and continue with the next row?

regards.

Comment: see `failwith` in plyr for the second part of your question.

Answer (score 2):

Part1: It's very likely that you could succeed with:

`ave( dataframe[, c("column1",   column2", column3", "column4", "column5", "column6")], myownfunction)`

Part2: If you modified the function to test for failure with `try` and returned `NA` when it fails you can fill in the missing data in the result properly.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have to questions:

1) Returning a value if failure happens.  As posted already, look at **failwith** in the plyr package. It does exactly this.

2) Speed up the for loop.  Have you tried using **mapply**? It is a multivariate apply that applies a function to the each element of each argument simultaneously. So

```
mapply(myfunc, column1, column2, column3, column4)
```

(along with modifying myfunc to use failwith) would do the sort of thing you are looking for.

The plyr version of mapply is mdply if you prefer.

Answer (score -1):

Got this from another forum, I like it more than the previous options:

```
R> M <- matrix(1:6, nrow=3, byrow=TRUE)

R> M

         [,1] [,2]
    [1,]    1    2

    [2,]    3    4

    [3,]    5    6
    R> apply(M, 1, function(x) 2*x[1]+x[2])

    [1]  4 10 16
```